# Formula to include "blank" if cell =0

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I worked out most of this but cannot get the last part which would require the cell to be showing "0" if another cell is blank. Here is what I tried most recently. This is in Google Sheets, in case it matters.

`=IF(B11>9.5,B11*0,IF(B11<9.5,B11+20-B11,IF(ISBLANK(B11),"",B11)))`

Comment: The title and body doesn't match. Please add some sample data showing the value of B11 and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(B11>9.5; B11*0; 
 IF(B11<9.5; B11+20-B11; 
 IF(B11=""; ""; B11)))
```

but I believe you need:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B11); B11>9.5); B11*0; 
 IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B11); B11<9.5); B11+20-B11; 
 IF(B11=""; ""; B11)))
```

...also `B11+20-B11` is pretty much same as to have there `20` instead

[image]